# USB connection issues

Tags: usb, hardware

not sure where to ask for help about this issue I've been having for quite a while, is this isn't the right place please do tell me the proper place where I can get help.

I've been having USB connection issues for a while on my computer, even before moving to Ubuntu. I don't know if the problem comes from my motherboard, power supply or something else.

Basically I get frequent disconnects of USB devices or moments where there aren't recognized as if they simply weren't there. This happens primarily with my keyboard on boot, where I have to wait or unplug it to be able to type my password and with my pen display tablet, that randomly disconnects making the pen unusable for a while.

I haven't had this problem with any of my devices on other Ubuntu computer I use, so I'm guessing it's a hardware problem on my main computer.
Please if you have any knowledge that can help me find a solution regarding this kind of issue I would be greatful.

My computer's basic specs :

- Motherboard : GIGABYTE Z97P-D3
- CPU : Intel Core i7-4790K @ 4.00GHz
- RAM : Ballistix Tactical DDR3 2 x 8 GB 1600 MHz CAS 8
- Drive : Samsung EVO 850 250 GB
- GPU : Nvdia GeForce GTX 1070
- PSU : Corsair RM750i

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Not a question for this site, only Ubuntu related questions here Try https://superuser.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll go that.